# How to open a jsp in a popup window based on an condition in struts2 Action class

Tags: jsp, struts2

I have a requirement to authenticate a user twice to two different systems. In order to achieve this when a user performs an action that looks into the other system, we popup a new login window and the user logs in. Then he can proceed with his operation.

The flow is Search.jsp - SearchAction 
SearchAction has the logic to check whether both systems are authenticated. 
If so, I need to load a popup with a loginpage and on entering the creds, it should close the popup and reload the contents on the parent page.

```
<action name="form" path="/search" scope="request" 
type="com.pack.SearchAction">
         <forward  name="success" path="/actualSearchpage.do"></forward>
         <forward  name="authFailure" path="/reAuth.do" module="/"> 
         </forward>
         <forward module="/" name="failure" path="/jsp//ErrorPage.jsp"></forward>
</action>
```

ReAuth Action has logic whether to display the searchpage or to display the relogin page. 
So that rules out my js option because at the time of clicking I don't know if the page will be a popup or is loaded in the same page.

```
<action path="/reAuth" scope="request" type="com.awpl.dsui.search.actions.ReAuthAction">
            <forward  name="failure" path="/jsp/reLogin.jsp" scope="session"></forward>
            <forward  name="success" path="/actualSearchPage.do"></forward>

</action>
```

Basically, I want the reLogin.jsp to be displayed in a popup window. While the regular search page to be displayed normally

Comment: Just to be clear... a jsp creates an html page. It is only the html and javascript which has control over the browser. What you are asking for has nothing to do with struts2 (except that you might want to create a service that returns a 200 code or some reasonable error code along with possibly a json response)... please partition your questions in such a way as to hide server side details if you want a JS solution. Please see the struts2-rest plugin (although I'm not a fan) and the struts2 json result type. I think reading about those might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
// you can use the following Code on click and call the method using JAVA Script
function reportWindow(id,mstFormId) {

    url="actionName?";
    url+="id="+id;
    winddd = window.open(url,"report",'width=800px,resizable=no, height=400px, menubar=no, toolbar=no, location=no, scrollbars=no');
    winddd.focus();
    }
```

Comment: But I don't know if it should open in the new window at the time of clicking.

Comment: Yes, It will open in new window, I think Yous desire for the same just like popup

Comment: I know how to open a new window. But the issue is something different. I have explained in the question details.